# How to retrieve Page content from streamfield in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, content-management-system, wagtail

I've created `SolutionPage` and inside It's `content` field there is nested `short_portfolio` block. I've added several `ProjectPage` instances via Wagtail admin panel to `PageChooserBlock`.

```
class SolutionPage(Page):
    ... 
    content = StreamField([
        ...
        ...
        ('short_portfolio', blocks.StructBlock([
            ('title', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('description', blocks.RichTextBlock(required=True)),
            ('projects', blocks.StreamBlock([
                ('project', blocks.PageChooserBlock(ProjectPage)),
            ], required=False, max_num=4)),
        ])),
    ], blank=True, null=True, validators=[UniqueProjectsInShortPortfolioValidator()])
```

Now, I'm working on **API view** for PDF export and **I need to extract all `ProjectPage` objects** from a given `SolutionPage`

```
import requests
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404

from portfolio.models import ProjectPage
from solutions.models import SolutionPage

class PortfolioToPdfView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        def get_404():
            return HttpResponse(
                render(
                    request=None,
                    template_name='404.html',
                    content_type="text/html"
                ),
                content_type='text/html'
            )

        path = request.META['PATH_INFO']
        if path.find('solutions') == -1:
            return get_404()
        slug = path[path[1:].find('/') + 2:]
        slug = slug[:slug.find('/')]

        solution_page = get_object_or_404(SolutionPage, slug=slug)
        short_portfolio = solution_page.content.stream_block.child_blocks["short_portfolio"]

        projects = [project.child_blocks["project"].target_model for project in short_portfolio.child_blocks["projects"]]

        ...
        response = HttpResponse(request, content_type='application/pdf')
        return response
```

The problem is that in this way I can only extract something like a "schema" of the page but not it's actual content.

```
TypeError at /solutions/ai-driven-machine-learning-software/portfolio-pdf/
'StreamBlock' object is not iterable
```

[Debug variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcE4F.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`solution_page.content.stream_block.child_blocks["short_portfolio"]` will give you the definition of the `short_portfolio` block, not a particular instance of that block. To do that, you'll need to iterate over the field contents, looking for a block that matches on `block_type`:

```
projects = []
for block in solution_page.content:
    if block.block_type == 'short_portfolio':
        for project_block in block.value['projects']:
            projects.append(project_block.value)
```